# Draw perpendicular line between two line strings in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, spatial

I have 2 line strings in the SQL Server.

```
declare @s geometry  = geometry::STGeomFromText
    (
        'LINESTRING('
        +     convert(varchar(max),35.688889,128) +' '+ convert(varchar(max),51.314722,128) -- 
        +', '+convert(varchar(max),32.750833,128) +' '+ convert(varchar(max),51.862778,128)+')',0 -- 
    );

declare @d geometry  = geometry::STGeomFromText
    (
        'LINESTRING('
        +     convert(varchar(max),34.761111,128) +' '+ convert(varchar(max),52.144444,128)
        +', '+convert(varchar(max),33.56,128) +' '+ convert(varchar(max),53.4475,128)+')',0
    );
```

How can I draw a line between them from the middle of `@s` with a `90-degree angle` to `@d`?

I have this code:

```
DECLARE @result geometry = @s.STEnvelope().STCentroid().ShortestLineTo(@d).ToString();
```

but this code just find the shortest line not perpendicular!

Comment: See https://i.stack.imgur.com/KILjO.png, p is perpendicular to d; do you want p to be perpendicular to s?

Comment: @RazvanSocol , p is perpendicular to d only if d is long enough to to intersect s. If D is short then you might get a line which is not perpendicular to d since `ShortestLineTo` find the shorter line which intersect both d and s.... This is very interesting question, which in first glance I assume that some math will be needed and we will not be able to count only on the build-in methods.

Comment: @RonenAriely: you are right, it is not always perpendicular.

Comment: I changed the input of the lines to make it clear that using ShortestLineTo method does not solve this scenario and I finished to find a solution but need to time to upload it as blog now. Here is the image of previous solution which does not works well and my solution. https://ibb.co/qsXfy9B

Answer (score 0):

draw an extended perpendicular line (to @s) which passes from the middle point of @s and crosses @d when possible(the extended line covers the plane of minX, maxX of all the points of the two lines @s&@d [or minY, maxY in case @s is horizontal])

```
declare @s geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText ( 'LINESTRING(' + convert(varchar(max),35.688889,128) +' '+ convert(varchar(max),51.314722,128) +', '+convert(varchar(max),32.750833,128) +' '+ convert(varchar(max),51.862778,128)+')',0)

declare @d geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText ( 'LINESTRING(' + convert(varchar(max),34.761111,128) +' '+ convert(varchar(max),52.144444,128) +', '+convert(varchar(max),33.56,128) +' '+ convert(varchar(max),53.4475,128)+')',0 )

--horizontal @s
--select @s = geometry::STGeomFromText ( 'LINESTRING(' + convert(varchar(max),35.688889,128) +' '+ convert(varchar(max),51.314722,128) +', '+convert(varchar(max),32.750833,128) +' '+ convert(varchar(max),51.314722,128)+')',0)
 
declare @extperpendicular geometry;

select @extperpendicular = geometry::STGeomFromText 
(
    concat('LINESTRING(',
    --start point of extended perpendicular to @s
    convert(varchar(100), case when pm is null then smidX else minX end, 2), ' ', convert(varchar(100), case when pm is null then minY else pm*minX + pc end, 2), 
    ',', 
    --end point of extended perpendicular to @s
    convert(varchar(100), case when pm is null then smidX else maxX end, 2), ' ', convert(varchar(100), case when pm is null then maxY else pm*maxX + pc end, 2), 
    ')')
, 0)

from
(
select
   p.*, 
   --middle point of @s is on perpendicular to @s --> smidY=pm*smidX+pc
   smidY-(pm*smidX) as pc,
   gbx.*,
   gby.*
from
(
    select *, -(sX2-sX1)/nullif(sY2-sY1, 0) as pm --slope of perpendicular to @s
    from
    (
    select  
      --mid point of @s
      @s.STEnvelope().STCentroid().STX as smidX, @s.STEnvelope().STCentroid().STY as smidY,
      --start point of @s
      @s.STStartPoint().STX as sX1, @s.STStartPoint().STY as sY1, 
      --end point of @s
      @s.STEndPoint().STX as sX2, @s.STEndPoint().STY as sY2
    ) as s
) as p
--boundaries of plane
--X
cross apply
(
    select min(h.x) as minX, max(h.x) as maxX
    from (values(@s.STStartPoint().STX),(@s.STEndPoint().STX),(@d.STStartPoint().STX),(@d.STEndPoint().STX)) as h(x)
) as gbx 
--Y. when @s is horizontal
cross apply
(
    select min(v.y) as minY, max(v.y) as maxY
    from (values(@s.STStartPoint().STY),(@s.STEndPoint().STY),(@d.STStartPoint().STY),(@d.STEndPoint().STY)) as v(y)
) as gby 
) as allpoints;

select * from (values(@s),(@d),(@extperpendicular)) as thelines(line);

--line between @s & @d
select @extperpendicular.STIntersection(@s).ToString() as startpoint, @extperpendicular.STIntersection(@d).ToString() as endpoint;
```